# How to disable sorting Group order in Datagrid, but keep sorting of columns within group?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I setup a `DataGrid` and bound it to an `ICollectionView` to which I added a group.

```
myView.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("MyProp"));
```

Then added a simple group style:

```
                <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="3"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                            <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                                <Expander.Header>
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" Margin="8,0,4,0"/>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="Element(s)"/>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </Expander.Header>
                                                <ItemsPresenter />
                                            </Expander>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

Anyways, the groups themselves are laid out initially in the order I want them in.  However, when a user clicks a header in the `DataGrid` to sort by that column, not only does it sort the column but it also sorts the Groups in order of their name.  So if my groups were B, A, C in that order, they'd be sorted to A, B, C and then the column within each group sorted.

Is there a simple setting somewhere to have the column sort only sort the columns and not also the group order.

To be clear I'm not asking how to disable sorting, just how to sort the columns within the groups without also reordering the groups themselves by name.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is any simple settings to sort data while groups are remain in the same order, however you can define a custom sorter and handle `DataGrid.Sorting` event to sort data based on desired order.

Assuming `Category` is the property which grouping is based on, we have something like this:

```
MyList.Add(new ItemViewModel { ID = 1, Amount = 5, Category = "A" , ...});
// add some more items

GroupedList = new ListCollectionView(MyList);
GroupedList.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Category"));
```

Then you need to write a custom sorter that sorts data based on your desired group order as primary sorting parameter (to keep groups order unchanged) and then sorts data by user selected column as secondary parameter (to sort data inside each group).

*Note that I wrote this assuming `Category` can only take "A", "B" and "C" and also your desired group order is B-A-C like you mentioned.*

```
public class CustomSorter : IComparer
{
    public ListSortDirection? Direction { get; set; }
    public string SortMember { get; set; }

    public CustomSorter(string sortMember, ListSortDirection? direction)
    {
        SortMember = sortMember;
        Direction = direction;
    }

    // A custom comparer based on group header ("Category" in this example) 
    // in "B"<"A"<"C" order.
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        var xVm = (ItemViewModel)x;
        var yVm = (ItemViewModel)y;

        if (xVm.Category == yVm.Category)
            return CompareBySortMember(xVm,yVm);
        if (xVm.Category == "B")
            return -1;
        if (xVm.Category == "A" && yVm.Category == "C")
            return -1;
        return 1;
    }

    // When two items have the same Category, comparison is made based on 
    // "SortMemberPath" property of the sorting column.
    private int CompareBySortMember(ItemViewModel xVm, ItemViewModel yVm)
    {
        var xValue = xVm.GetType().GetProperty(SortMember).GetValue(xVm);
        var yValue = yVm.GetType().GetProperty(SortMember).GetValue(yVm);
        int result = xValue.ToString().CompareTo(yValue.ToString());
        return Direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? result * -1 : result;
    }
}
```

And finally:

```
    private void DataGrid_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;

        // Set the sort order on the column
        e.Column.SortDirection = (e.Column.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending) 
            ? ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;

        // Sort data based on predefined order of group headers and currently sorting column.
        GroupedList.CustomSort = new CustomSorter(e.Column.SortMemberPath, e.Column.SortDirection);
    }
```